# For an $n$-tournament, what's a tight upper bound for the minimum number of transitive sub tournaments needed to edge cover it?

Tags: graph-theory

Given an $n$-tournament, is there a known tight upper bound for the minimum number of transitive sub tournaments needed to edge cover the original tournament?

Context:
Studying causal graphs in relativistic quantum information

Comment: I think there are tournaments of order $n$ whose largest transitive subtournament has at most $2\lg n$ nodes (or something like that). If that's right, I think that will give you a lower bound of something like $\frac14(n/\lg n)^2$ for the number of tournaments you need.

Comment: @bof Yes, they are. Namely, in the paper "[On the representation of directed graphs as unions of orderings](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1964-22.pdf)" by P. Erdős and L. Moser  (Magyar Tud. Akad. Mat. Kutató Int. Közl., **9** (1964), 125–132) is proved that there are tournaments on $n$ vertices without a transitive subtournament of size $2+2\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor $ and this bound  is rather tight, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29#Ramsey_theory).

Answer (score 2):

There is a paper “[Decomposing oriented graphs into transitive tournaments](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X05005856)” by Raphael Yuster (Discrete Mathematics **306**:1 (2006) 166 – 170) where is considered a function $f(G)$ denoting the minimum number of transitive subtournaments that decompose an oriented graph $G$ with $n$ vertices (a decomposition is a cover which covers each edge exactly once). It is proved that $f(G)<\tfrac{5}{21}n^2(1 + o(1))$ (or, more precisely, $f(G)\le\tfrac{6946273}{29174348}n^2(1 + o(1)$, see the last page) for each tournament $G$  and there are tournaments $G$ for which $f(G)>n^2/3000$.

Comment: This is very nice! Actually I am interested in coverings that allow edges to be used more than once. I wonder if it is easy to get this bound from here...

Comment: @cplusplusguru Yes, I understood that in your question we can use edges several times. Therefore only the upper bound fits for your question and the lower bound is not applicable (I read the paper). So there remains an asymptotic gap between the lower bound of $\Omega((n/\ln n)^2)$ and the upper bound $O(n^2)$, which looks not so easy to be improved.